# How to create a text file from an existing Pdf document in C#.net

Tags: c#, pdf

I have PDF document data with table structure format and I would like to convert that PDF file into a text file with the same structure with margin and spaces between text in pdf

Comment: "Without using third party tools" is very brave decision. In that case you need to write your own tool for reading PDF..

Comment: Why do you have the requirement to do it without 3rd party tools, why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

You need to write your own PDF tool then. Which is not exactly an easy task. Honestly, 3rd party tools make your job much easier, why don't you want to use one?

If you change your mind, I can suggest iTextSharp. I've used it in the past with great success. Here are some example to get you going:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12445/Converting-PDF-to-Text-in-C

ps. there are 3 tools used in there.

Comment: xIcarus , I have seen this article which u have given in that link.. It is extracting data to text file but I needed the margin and spaces between text exactly like in pdf document.